# copied boot partition to ssd and windows fails to boot

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, ssd

I just got an ssd, my main drive has 2 partitions. The second one stores some large installed apps, but nothing should be used for bootup that I know of(there maybe a few things, not sure, but shouldn't prevent windows from hanging).

When I boot off the ssd, windows 8 goes to the welcome screen trying to load my profile(right after it should go to the desktop). Instead it just hangs.

This happens only if I remove the original HD with the 2 partitions on it. If I connect them back(i.e., attach the sata cable), the SSD boots and seems to be the booted drive(although it is not C but F, the same as in the original OS, which might be the problem).

My guess is that windows is trying to use something off that partition(possibly a device driver of something I installed), or just being an dork! I only run with critical services, so no stupid stuff is running in the background.

If it is the drive(or a good chance, How do I get windows to recognize it)? I've not had a problem before with the drives. Usually windows sets the boot drive to C, but in this case it keeps the boot drive as F(what it was before I cloned it).

I used EasyBCD and EaseUS.

1. With just the SSD drive, windows boots up to the welcome screen, about to go into desktop. Hence, it has the OS file so on the drive. (Else it couldn't get into windows at all).
2. Windows only gets to the desktop if I plug in the original drive(but still booting off the SSD). I've plugged in the original HD after the SSD was booting, so I know it booting off the SSD first.

This suggests windows needs files on the original drive, but it doesn't... Probably just looking in the wrong place.

One thing I did forget to do is add a system partition like you get when windows installs. Not sure if that matters(doubt it since this seems to be a profile issue, not an install issue).

Any ideas?

P.S. While booted off the SSD, I changed the original HD's drive letter and immediately lost my profile(all desktop icons gone, taskbar has no start menu, quicklaunch, etc....

It seems that the SSD OS tries to load the profile on the original HD instead of the SSD(even though it's there)... I guess it's some security issue but I've never had the problem before.

Comment: I don't see how this is off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, even though I booted from F, it seems windows was looking from the profile information on C. Even when C was gone, it wouldn't use F. I had to get the drive F to turn in to C. To do this, I simply removed all entries in HKLM\SYSTEM\MountedDevices. This caused windows to reorder the drives and it happened to rename the F drive to C(I suppose it could have gotten it wrong, and it did for the second partition, which I simply renamed in the mounted devices and rebooted).

To do what I did, since my profile was gone(when I took the original C drive offline to try and rename the F drive, which didn't work inside windows as it complained and I lost my profile(desktop, start menu, etc vaninished), I was able to run task manager(right mouse on the void taskbar), then run admin regedit from that.

Comment: Great that you found an answer and shared it with us. Please mark your answer as "accepted", otherwise it keeps popping up in the "unanswered" lists. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The boot drive in Windows has to be the "C:" drive. When you cloned the OS files to the SSD, you needed to disconnect the C: drive, designate in the BIOS to boot with just the SSD and then change its drive letter before you actually boot up into Windows so Windows will see the C drive again. Once that is done and the SSD, all by itself , has booted to windows, you shut down, reconnect the old C drive, making it a second drive in the system and before you boot up to windows, change its drive letter in the BIOS to F: and then start over and boot up to windows with the SSD as the C: drive and the HDD as the F: drive.

Some of the speed increase when using the SSD is because you now have two drives searching and reading files when before you only had one. The throughput of the storage system is the biggest cause of lag time and poor responsiveness if you already have sufficient ram. I suggest you partition the hard drive and put your favorite games on the first several partitions, at the beginning. Use the last partition for pictures, documents, e-mail, Facebook, your browsers, and perhaps maintenance programs like Auslogics Defragment and Glary Utilities. Programs that clean up your hard drive don't need to be on a fast partition. They are less taxing than most games and the hard drive won't be rushed anyways.

Your browsers don't require speed either. The slowness that people are experiencing with Firefox and Google Chrome is due to the various ISP, along with Microsoft, using your CPU and RAM to calculate and transmit commercial data using bandwidth while you browse the Internet. When you are on a single page and nothing on the page is moving, there shouldn't be 300-500megabyte of ram being using and your CPU active with 20-50% output. That's when your computer is being used as a server and that's how all that commercail "Flash" advertising you see is being transmitted to other shoppers browsers as well as your own. Its also a good idea to put the temp files, cookies and browser history files on the hard drive and not the SSD. Lastly, you can keep a copy of the Operating system on one small partition of the hard drive at the beginning "just in case" the SSD fails and you need to re-designate the hard drive as the C: drive again. Don't get into a twist about "updates" either. I've run a whole year without updating and the result is I had less trouble rather than more but I do use a great anti-virus and have it set to dig slow and deep on every frequent scan, monitoring my browsers and I keep my ports at a minimum which drives my ISP nuts but that's THEIR problem.

Comment: "The boot drive in Windows has to be the "C:" drive" is completely wrong. In the past I've had dual boot systems with Windows XP on drive C and Windows NT on drive D (or was it the other way around?)